# Set a variable passed to a function?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to put a variable name within a variable passed to a function, and perform an operation on it.

Here is my code (simplified):

```
function animloop(object, increment, max, direction) {
  if (direction == 1) {
    object += increment;

    if (object >= max) {
      clearInterval( pingpong.animloop );
    }
  }

  if (direction == -1) {
    object -= increment;

    if (object <= max) {
      clearInterval( pingpong.animloop );
    }
  }

}
```

If I first set the variable `xyz = 10;` and then call `pingpong.animloop = setInterval( animloop( xyz, 0.1, 40, 1 ) ), 1000 / 60 );`, it won't work.

What I learned is that when I call `object += increment;`, it isn't actually modifying the value of whatever `object` is. Basically the value of `xyz` isn't changing.

Hopefully you understand what I'm trying to do. :/

Comment: Numbers are immutable in JavaScript.

Comment: Then how is it that I have always been able to modify variables I have already set?

Comment: @ryansworld10 You haven't modified the number itself. You've caused a variable, object property, or array index to reference a _new_ number. Variables don't "hold" objects or values, they reference them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive data types are passed by-value in JS, which means you're not accessing the `xyz` you defined outside of the function call. You're accessing some OTHER variable that has been given a copy of the value `xyz` had at the time of the function call.

There's a few ways around it.

global vars:

```
var xyz = 123;
animLoop(inc,max,dir); // note, no xyz argument
function animLoop(i,m,d) {
   xyz++; // global scope xyz is now 124
}
```

return value:

```
xyz = 123;
xyz = animLoop(xyz, max, dir);
function animLoop(obj, max, dir) {
    obj++;
    return(obj);
}
```

or use an object. Objects are passed by reference, so this would work:

```
xyz = { value: 123; }
animLoop(xyz, max, dir);
function animLoop(obj, max, dir) {
    obj.value++; // xyz.value is now 124
}
```

Comment: Downvoted until you fix your last code snippet to not be wrong. _(Hint: `xyz = { value:42 };`)_

Comment: This is perfect, I used the object workaround and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to look up a local variable by name, you're basically "doing it wrong" :)

Instead, create an object to house related properties and look up the property by name. In JavaScript, every property of every object can be referenced either by `foo.bar` or `foo["bar"]`; the latter is necessary when the property name is not a legal identifier (e.g. `my form.elements["names[]"]`) or—as in your case—when you want to look up a property based on a variable.

```
var props = {a:0, b:0};
increment(props,'a');
console.log( props.a ); //1

function increment(obj,propName){
  obj[propName]+=1;
}
```

*Note that in a browser you **can** access global variables as properties of the `window` object that is your Global context, e.g.*

```
foo = 42;
var myVar = "foo";
console.log( window[myVar] ); // 42
```

*…but this is still usually a bad idea, ripe with possibilities for a naming collision. Use custom objects to group related properties.*